# War deployment exception: Parser configuration exception parsing XML from Ser vletContext resource

Tags: xml, jboss, wildfly, xerces, saaj

I try to deploy a War on jboss, but am getting exception as :

Jboss logs :

> {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"WFL
> YCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit."acs-init.war".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeE
> xception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Parser configuration exception parsing XML from Ser
> vletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/properties/acs-ws-context.xml]; nested exception is javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurat
> ionException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactor
> yImpl@293fa923] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Ja
> va 1.5) for full XSD support.
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Parser configurati
> on exception parsing XML from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/properties/acs-ws-context.xml]; nested exception is j
> avax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.in
> ternal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@293fa923] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson
> ? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support.
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Parser configuration exception parsing XML fro
> m ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/properties/acs-ws-context.xml]; nested exception is javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfi
> gurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderF
> actoryImpl@293fa923] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (
> or Java 1.5) for full XSD support.
> Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [com.sun.org.
> apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@293fa923] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 wit
> h Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support.
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration incompatible with org.apache.
> xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration"}}}}

From POM.xml :

...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>${xercesImpl.xercesImpl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

...

When i remove the xerces dependecy from pom.xml and remove the jar from the lib the war is deployed but it doesnt work, i have this response from soap api :

```
     <html>
   <head>
      <title>Error</title>
   </head>
   <body>Internal Server Error</body>
</html>
```

I tried many solutions like adding in /jboss-eap-7.3/bin/standalone.conf jvm arguments but nothing seems to work.

```
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4000m -Xmx4000m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl"
else
...
```

Ps : when i replace xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar TO xercesImpl-2.6.2-jaxb-1.0.6.jar in the lib,
and i add in standalone.conf this arguments the war is deploying but in soap i have an error

Argments added:

```
-Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPFactory1_1Impl 
-Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnectionFactory -Djavax.xml.soap.MetaFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl
```

Error in soapui :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:ns1="octo.com">ns1:8</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Problems creating SAAJ object model</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can i solve this problem please ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to provide a JAXB implementation. Try leaving the xerces implementation out of your pom.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, but when i coment the dependency of xerces, the war is deploying but the services doesnt work..

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? JAXB is provided by the container and shouldn't be in your deployment.

Comment: I mean that the original war contains 'xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar' and i cant deploy it , when i replace the jar with xercesImpl-2.6.2-jaxb-1.0.6.jar , the war deploy but the services in soapui returns internal error, idem when i delete the dependency of xerces in pom.xml, the war deploy but internal error in soapui

Comment: Can you try deploying your WAR with any xerces JAR? It should not be required.

Comment: I tried with several versions but the war cant be deployed(https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xerces/xercesImpl/) , when by chance i tried xercesImpl-2.6.2-jaxb-1.0.6.jar it can be deployed but the services doesnt work in soapui

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a typo. I meant without any xerces JAR. The server should provide the functionality.

Comment: I tried to deploy without the jar but the services doesnt work when i test it in soapui